# PHP: Поиск части слова в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка со списком слов. Есть определенное слово, которое нужно найти в этой строке.
Я использую функцию `strpos()`, всё ок:

```
$mystring = 'apple,orange,pear,banana,mango';
$findme   = 'apple';

$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

if ($pos !== false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
} else {
     echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring'";
}
```

Однако, я хотел бы сделать поиск немного гибким, чтобы поиск осуществлялся по частям искомого слова.
Например, слово для поиска будет не "**apple**", а "**pineapple**". В нашем случае функция ничего не найдет.

Я думаю, что можно эту задачу можно решить путем поиска каждого слова из списка 
 в строке `$findme`:

```
$mystring = 'apple,orange,pear,banana,mango';
$findme   = 'pineapple';
$arr= explode(",", $mystring );

foreach($arr as $v){
    $pos = strpos($findme, $v);

    if ($pos !== false) {
        echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring'";
        echo " в позиции $pos";
        break;
    } else {
         echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring'";
    }
}
```

Но а если словарь `$mystring` состоит из сотен тысяч слов. Тогда мой вариант будет работать очень медленно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Спасибо!

Comment: _сделать поиск немного гибким, чтобы поиск осуществлялся по частям искомого слова._ - для этого существуют регулярные выражения.

Comment: @Эдуард Могли бы продемонстрировать это выражение?

Comment: Да, сейчас набросаю пример.

Comment: Это задача поиска наибольшей общей подстроки, что ли?

Comment: @Akina Есть слово "pineapple", Нужно найти совпадения в строке, где присутствует просто "apple".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью регулярных выражений, поиск не точных вхождений в подстроку можно организовать так:

```
$mystring = 'apple,orange,pear,banana,mango and pineapple';
$findme   = 'apple';

$patt = preg_quote($findme, '~');
preg_match_all("~\w*$patt\w*~", $mystring, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

---

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => pineapple
        )

)
```

---

> *нужно, чтобы строка $mystring = $mystring = 'apple,orange,pear,banana,mango', а $findme = 'pineapple'; И в $matches я увидел результат, что найдено*

Тогда можно исходную строку использовать как шаблон:

```
$mystring = 'apple,orange,pear,banana,mango';
$findme   = 'pineapple';

$patt = join('|', explode(',', $mystring));
preg_match_all("~$patt~", $findme, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

---

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
        )

)
```

Comment: Это понятно, что регулярные выражения:) Но нужно, чтобы строка  $mystring = 'apple,orange,pear,banana,mango', а $findme   = 'pineapple';  И в $matches я увидел результат, что найдено!

Comment: спасибо Вам большое! А не подскажите зачем нужно было делать разделитель в строке "|"?

Comment: @Pavel в регулярных выражениях символ "|" - это оператор альтернативного выбора "ИЛИ". Таким образом, шаблон запрограммирован на поиск слова: apple ИЛИ orange ИЛИ pear ИЛИ banana ИЛИ mango.

Comment: @Pavel если до сих пор не дошло, это будет работать так же медленно. Особенно с тем кривым кодом, который тут написан. Уже на тысче слов этот код тупо будет падать с ошибкой

Comment: @Ипатьев, Вы могли бы как-то аргументировать свои ответы? Если вы считаете ответы участников недостаточно точными или не совсем правильными, почему бы вам не предложить свой конкретизированный ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Поиск по сотням тысяч слов, состряпанный на коленке в РНР скрипте будет всегда работать медленно. Для поиска по сотням тысяч слов следует использовать другие механизмы.
Самый простой - поместить слова в базу данных.

Comment: Каким тогда должен будет выглядеть запрос, помимо WHERE LIKE "% СЛОВО %"?

Comment: @Pavel так можно регулярные выражения использовать. Первая ссылка из гугла: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_predicate_like/page2.html

Comment: Но если у вас изначально идет именно в php строка, то вам ее придется разделять, заносить в бд, и скорее всего это тоже не очень хорошо отразится на производительности.

Comment: дадад, изначально php строка из сотен тысяч слов

Comment: @AntonSorokin, Ипатьев, Ну хорошо. Для сотен тысяч слов, наверное не сильно хорошая идея использовать регулярные выражения. При большом количестве запросов скорости диска просто не хватит. Использовать MySQL я пробовал. При 100к запрос выполняется 0,05 сек с учетом идексации, что тоже не совсем хорошо. Наверное, лучше использовать in-memory решения типа Redis или др. На Redisе такое не поднять, мне кажется. Только если использовать Lua, но это слишком уж сложно. Я думал, все проще должно быть.

Comment: @Pavel поиск через LIKE "% СЛОВО %" с пробелами наводит на очень нехорошие мысли о структуре данных. поиск через  LIKE "%СЛОВО%" (без пробелов) по очевидным причинам не исмпользует индекс. Поиск по вхождению подстроки вообще всегда будет медленным, какое решение не используй. Надо сделать так, чтобы поиск был по точному совпадению, или хотя бы вида WHERE LIKE "СЛОВО%"

Comment: @Ипатьев Я знаю, что LIKE очень медленный, уж лучше использовать отдельный движок полнотекстового поиска типа Sphinx или ElasticSearch. Проблема в том, как  получить это точное слово по которому будет производиться поиск. Идея держать в базе корневое слово, например "banana", а искать "12banana" или "ASbananaLL". Т.е. если пользователь ошибается в вводе, я имел возможность выдать наиболее релевантный результат. В MySQL сделал типа регулярки на PHP, но опять-таки LIKE.  WHERE  'ASbananaLL' LIKE CONCAT('%', fruitsColumn, '%')

Comment: @Pavel сфинкс и эластик - это системы полно**текстового** поиска. Они ищут текст. "мама мыла раму". И система пытается найти все записи, которые могли бы соответствовать этой фразе. по подстрокам они не ищут. Нормализация пользовательского ввода - это отдельная тема. И если такая проблема стоит, то именно про нее и надо вопрос задавать. А не про свои попытки её решить на коленке.